# Add multiple dir for static files in Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

Loopback has two areas where paths are set for static files:

server.js

```
   var path = require('path');
   app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));
```

middleware.json

```
"files": {
    "loopback#static": {
      "params": "$!../client"
      }
  },
```

In my dev environment I'd also like to reference another dir for example `/node_modules`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Register `loopback.static` multiple times in `server.js`:

```
...
app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));
app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../other-dir')));
...
```

The first one has highest precedence. See http://expressjs.com/api.html for more info.

You can do it with phases too, inside your `middleware.json` (See [docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+middleware#Definingmiddleware-Middlewareconfigurationproperties)):

```
"files": {
    "loopback#static": [{
        "name": "client",
        "paths": ["/client"],
        "params": "$!../client"
    },
    {
        "name": "someother",
        "paths": ["/someother"],
        "params": "$!../someother"
    }]
}
```

Comment: It work perfectly using the given description for middleware.json without modifying the server.js, Thanks

Comment: Note: `[` and `]` in the `middleware.json` method.

Comment: How would I achieve serving a static file based on the subdomain rather than the path?

I want to serve `app1` for subdomain1.app.com and `app2` for subdomain2.app.com